# How to delete a file in the MediaStore to avoid any issue when writing files in the external storage (Android 13)

Tags: android, delphi, java-native-interface, c++builder

Back to square one as I still have not solved the issue.
Here is a more detailed recap of the problem.

I try to copy the file "abcdef.dat" from "/data/user/0/com.myapp/files/abcedf.dat" to "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myapp/abcdef1234.dat"

It worked without any issues with the previous version of android but not as expected with android 13. After a while (many debugging sessions), I could not copy the file in the destination folder anymore.

I have uninstalled and deleted the destination folder, reinstalled the app and recreated the folder but it does not solve the issue. I simply can not create the "abcdef1234.dat" in the destination folder anymore. I can create files with new names but not "abcdef1234.dat"

The folder "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myapp" is empty but when I try to create the file (traditional C/C++way), the file handler is always null

When I check if the file exists with `System::Ioutils::TFile::Exist`, the function returns false which is expected as the destination folder is empty. However when I try to copy the file with the `System::Ioutils::TFile::Copy` function, it returns a fatal error with the message "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myapp/abcdef1234.dat" does already exist.

It makes me mad as I can not figure why it is happening.

As the issue might be linked with the MediaStore, I tried a very basic function to delete the ghost entries of "abcdef1234.dat"

Here is the function

```
int mediastore_cleanup(AnsiString filename)
    {
    //C++ builder syntax
    TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JString> *selectionArgs = new TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JString>(1);
    _di_Jnet_Uri uri_collection;
    _di_JContentResolver content;
    _di_JString selection;


    uri_collection=TJMediaStore_Files::JavaClass->getContentUri(StringToJString("internal"));
    selection=StringToJString("_display_name = ?");
    selectionArgs->Items[0]=StringToJString(filename);


    content = TAndroidHelper::Activity->getContentResolver();
    int delcnt=content->Delete(uri_collection,selection,selectionArgs);

    return(delcnt);
    }
```

but when I call `mediastore_cleanup("abcdef1234.dat")` mediastore_cleanup always returns 0 and it is still impossible to create "abcdef1234.dat" in the destination file

My questions are:

- why it is happening?
- is it due to the MediaStore?
- if the problem comes from MediaStore, should the `mediastore_cleanup()` function work as it is? Should it find the file entry without the RELATIVE_PATH (sure it is a bit sloppy but a this stage I just want to confirm the origin of the problem) ?
- if you need the RELATIVE and the DISPLAY_NAME how do I formulate the delete query?
- do I need to add a permission to the manifest?

Comment: No idea which path you use. Please just tell the value. What is it that your code instantiates?

Comment: `I could create this directory and write/read files in this directory ` Did you do that in the classic way or via a MediaStore insert()?

Comment: The path is "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myapp/". I create the file in the traditional way : f=(FILE*) fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myapp/myfile.txt","wt");

Comment: Your code is unreadable. We cannot see the values you use for the variables and parameters. Nor are you telling values of intermediate results. Also you are not using relative path column.

Comment: Further the code is unreadable where you first declare all the variables instead of there where you first need them. Its an old C programming habit it looks like.

Comment: We have no idea what StringToJString() does or why you use it.

Comment: `while(cursor->moveToFirst())` That looks like an endless loop.

Comment: `//delete the entry` Yes. Where is the code?

Comment: Very old C programming habit indeed but still widely used.

Comment: StringToJString() is used to convert AnsiString to _di_JString (C++ builder JNI function)

Comment: //delete entry, indicates where to insert the delete entry function. Without the delete function,  it is indeed an endless loop. I should have been more explicit.

Comment: I have added few more comments in the code.  My issue is at the beginning of the code with the function **`uri_collection=mediastore_filesclass->getContentUri(StringToJString(path));'** This is not the right way to do it with C++ Builder and my question is how to properly do it in C++ Builder (or delphi).

Comment: You cannot get a content uri for a path.

Comment: `Without the delete function, it is indeed an endless loop` With the delete funtion too. The cursor count will not change at a delete. And you should first build the uri.

Comment: Thank you Backapps for all your replies. Unfortunately I'm still stuck. What it is the best way to access and delete these ghost entries in the "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myapp/" folder?

Comment: That i already told you. RELATIVE_PATH="Documents/myapp"  and DISPLAY_NAME="file name". And use the right collection.

Comment: I know that, but I can not retrieve the external storage uri. I'm supposed to call the getContentUri() function of the MediaStore.Files class but the way I do it is not right. It is initialized as mediastore_files=TJMediaStore_Files::Create(); in the code above, but it returns a null pointer and when I call mediastore_files->getContent, the app crash (of course). The question is what is the correct way to initialize the MediaStore.Files class and how to call the getContentUri function in C++ builder or Delphi. Once I have the uri_collection I can perform the query as you suggested.

Comment: I do not program c++builder for Android. I have no idea. Strange that you cannot find this basic code.

Comment: Unfortunately C++ builder is a dead end for apps programming as there is no android 64 bits compiler and they don't plan to make one soon. However Delphi is up to date and it is very easy to adapt code from C++ builder to Delphi and vice versa. However I could not find a single line of Delphi code online which shows how to interact with the Android.MediaStore. I wonder how the other users do this as the use of MediaStore is almost mandatory on Android 13 if you want to access the external storage....

Comment: Anyway, thank you Backapps for your inputs!

Comment: Without needing any permission you have access in the classical way to all public directories on Android 13 devices.

Comment: I found it! In C++ builder/delphi, you call the media_store.files **'getContentUri()'** function with the following command **'uri_collection=TJMediaStore_Files::JavaClass->getContentUri(StringToJString("/storage/emulated/0/"));'**

Comment: It does not work. back to square one (see updated description of the question)

Answer (score 0):

You should query() the MediaStore for your file.

Use DISPLAY_NAME and RELATIVE_PATH with the values for your file.

If you get an uri you can use a delete() on this uri.

This will not only delete the entry in the MediaStotre but also the file itself.

But better use MediaStore.createDeleteRequest() where possible.

Answer (score 0):

After spending few more days, I was able to isolate the issue.

It is not linked to C++ builder/Delphi or the mediastore but a behaviour of Android 13 in debugging mode.

My app had a bug related to the use of the GPS (was not a bug with android 9). It was severe enough for Android 13 to shutdown and isolate the files of my app. I don't know the protection mechanism used by Android 13 but Android might have treated my app as a malicious software and then had isolated the files generated by my buggy app after a while (see my first post for a description of the symptoms).

I have corrected the GPS bug since and now my app works perfectly well and I don't have any restriction on the file names usage anymore. Note this is how I see the situation as Android 13 never fired some kind of violation/malicious software message.

This android 13 behavior made the debugging of my app very difficult as once the android protection activated, it makes the app stops because it could not access/create config files...

I'm surprised this hidden protection mechanism is enabled in debugging mode. Without any warning message, It is impossible to know the reason why the app stopped and why the files has been blacklisted.

My knowledge of Android is too limited to know where this protection mechanism sits in the system and how to disable it in debugging mode.

Today, the app works perfectly well, but I can still not access to the blacklisted filenames. This will be a question for a next thread.